# ROS Cmake won't see boost library

Tags: ros, c++, boost, linking, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I am currently writing a cpp in my ROS package based on this [tutorial](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/vfh_recognition.php#vfh-recognition) but there seems to be a linking error as the `boost::filesystem` classes aren't recognized.

I've searched for an answer  on the Internet and only found the suggestion to add `#define BOOST_FILESYSTEM_VERSION 2` after the #include for boost,which unfortunately doesn't help and there were also suggestions of explicitly linking to boost_system in my CMakeLists.txt but since I've only started using cmake since I've begun ROS I don't know to do much beyond adding executables.

I am working on Ubuntu 11.10 the boost libraries include with it are 1.46.1 and I am working with ROS electric and I feel the need to mention that I've used boost shared pointers in this package before without needing to add any includes or dependencies.

Any answers on what I need to add to my CMakeList.txt, if that is where I need to work, would be greatly appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/30662/ros-cmake-won%27t-see-boost-library/) by [George B.](https://answers.ros.org/users/2069/george-b./) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2012-03-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I believe you need to first add

```
rosbuild_add_boost_directories()
```

And then link against the library you want to use with

```
rosbuild_link_boost(target lib1 lib2 lib3 ...)
```

You were probably able to use shared pointers because the boost lib that includes those is header only and there's no need to link with anything.

---

Originally posted by [Miguel Prada](https://answers.ros.org/users/164/miguel-prada/) with karma: 1071 on 2012-03-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1